# Want to display db value in my page. The Add and view should in one page

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function unit_list()
  {
    //Redirect in case of session out
    if (!$this->session->userdata ( 'user_id' )) {
      redirect ( $this->config->base_url (), 'refresh' );
      return false;
    }
     $this->load->model('Unit_model');
    $arrWhere = array("vchr_unit_status"=>"A");
        $data ["unit"]=$this->Unit_model->get_all($arrWhere);
        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('includes/left_menu');
        $this->load->view('unit/manage',$data);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
  }
```

This is my controller . The unit_list is the function i wrote to get all data from db and view that in my view page

```
class Unit_model extends CI_Model{
protected $strTableName = 'suc_unit';
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct ();
            $CI = &get_instance();
            $this->db->from($this->strTableName);  
        }


        /**
        *
        */
        function get_all($arrWhere)
        {
            $this->db->where($arrWhere);
            $q1 = $this->db->get();
            $result = $q1->result_array();  
            return $result;
        }
```

This is my model

```
                              <table id="tblListOfUnits" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <tr>
                                  <th style="width: 10px">Sl No</th>
                                  <th>Unit Name</th>
                                  <th>Unit Symbol</th>

                                </tr>
                                <?php
                                if(!isset($unit)){
                                    $count = 1;
                                 foreach ($unit as $key => $units) {  
                                ?>
                                <tr id="tr_<?php echo $units->pk_int_unit_id; ?>">
                                    <td id="tdUntSlNo_<?php echo isset($units) ? $units['int_no_decimal']: ' '; ?>><a href="javascript:unitEdit(<?php echo $unit->pk_int_unit_id; ?>)" ><?php echo $count; ?>.</a></td>
                                    <td id="tdUntNme_<?php echo $units->pk_int_unit_id; ?>"><a href="javascript:unitEdit(<?php echo $unit->pk_int_unit_id; ?>)" ><?php echo $unit->vchr_unit_name; ?></a></td>
                                    <td id="tdUntSymbl_<?php echo $units->pk_int_unit_id; ?>"><a href="javascript:unitEdit(<?php echo $unit->pk_int_unit_id; ?>)" ><?php echo $unit->vchr_unit_symbol; ?></a></td>

                                </tr>
                                <?php  
                                    $count ++;
                                    }
                                }?>
                              </table>
```

This is my view page. please help me to view all the data in my view page. Im new to codeigniter so i dont know how to use get_all function to view the data in my page.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter allows you to pass the data to the view in a couple of ways. First, if you would simply use the second parameter of the view method, then your data would be available as `$unit` in the view.

In your code, it seems that you are doing that. That means that in your unit/manage.php view, the result of your query should be available as `$unit`.

A couple of things though. When you load a model, calls to that model are lowercased.

```
$this->unit_model->get_all( $arrWhere );
```

It may not matter, but that line should be:

```
$data["unit"] = $this->unit_model->get_all( $arrWhere );
```

I want to point out that in your model's method, you are assuming that you will always have a result, and that's not OK. You need to make sure there's a result before trying to return it. Also, you need to provide a table name to get():

```
function get_all( $arrWhere )
{
    // Make sure $arrWhere is an array
    if( ! is_array( $arrWhere ) )
        return FALSE;

    $this->db->where( $arrWhere );

    // Make sure you set the table name!
    $q1 = $this->db->get( $this->strTableName );

    // Make sure there is a result set!
    if( $q1->num_rows() > 0 )
        return $q1->result_array();

    return FALSE; // or NULL, or array(), or whatever you want.
}
```

Sure, you are trying to set the table in the constructor of the model, but that would only work for the first query to the database. That's not right, and you should avoid that because typically you don't create a model just for a single query.

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // If you are in a CodeIgniter model, you don't need this line
    // $CI = &get_instance();

    // This is bad. Don't do this ever.
    // $this->db->from($this->strTableName);  
}
```

Now in your view you have a problem. `$unit` will ALWAYS be set, so when you do this:

```
if( ! isset( $unit ) ) ...
```

You will never enter that block of code. What you should be doing there is:

```
if( ! empty( $unit ) ) ...
```

In your foreach loop, this code will throw an error:

```
$units->pk_int_unit_id
```

It's because you are returning an array of arrays from your db call, so it should be:

```
$units['pk_int_unit_id']
```

You've got other instances where you're trying to use an object that is actually an array. Basically anywhere that you have `$units->` it should be `$units['...']`.

If you wany to use an object instead of an array, then inside get_all() you should use:

```
return $q1->result();
```

Because `result_array()` is an array of arrays, but `result()` is an array of objects.

Anyways, hope this helps.

Comment: still the same problem exits

Comment: You should do a couple of things. Verify that your query result set actually has rows. What I mean is to debug the value returned by get_all(). You could use var_dump() or even better you could use ChromePHP and log to your browser's console. Secondly, if you edit your question to show your revised code it may help me see where your problem is. Try to improve your code indent so it is very clear.